# Spotfire TERR text mining error: "name must be a single string"

Tags: r, tm, spotfire, terr

I am trying to create a script that does text mining (tm) combining property and action controls with TERR.

I have run my script successfully in open-source R but keep getting an error in TERR. I have narrowed down the function causing the error to VCorpus, part of the tm package. Here is the portion of the script causing errors:

```
myinput <- do.call(paste, c(as.list(col1), sep=" "))
```

> Col1 is a document property (string) based on selection from property
>   control drop down list.

```
b <- VCorpus(VectorSource(myinput), readerControl = list(language = 'eng'))
```

... and the error message I get in TERR is:

> TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R returned an error: 'Error in
>   getS3method("pGetElem", class(x), TRUE) : 'name' must be a single
>   string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution from Tibco developers community

Answer:
You will not face this error if you use TERR 4.1.

There was a bug which got fixed in version 4.1

Reference :

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.1.0/TIB_terr_4.1.0_relnotes.pdf

### See below fix on page 16

TERR-6049  The getS3method function now works when the class argument is of

### length greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am at this point too.
I can do well using open R engine but in TERR I am trying to solve this error.

I am suspecting about the data format expected by TERR.

Comment: I suspect the data structure as being the problem as well. Note that the Corpus function calls the generic S3 function "pGetElem". The object being passed into the Corpus has class attribute of a vector string (because of the VectorSource function) rather than a single element character string which TERR expects.  I suspect this is what is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks! I have opened a ticket at tibco and they answer the same for me.